# SQL query dont work correct in postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a simple SQL query where help me to find it the values have some English letter in text of field.

here the SQL :

```
select id,field1 
from mytable 
where mytable like '[A-Z]'
```

that query work nice in MS-ACCESS database but not work on DB MANAGER on QGIS and postgis query because I think Postgres doesn't recognize the list of alphabet [A-Z].

if I use this :

```
select id,field1 
from mytable 
where mytable like '%A%' 
   or mytable like '%B%'......
```

then it works but I don't like this method.

In Postgres:

```
select public.mytable.id,public.mytable.field1 
from mytable 
where public.mytable.mytable like '[A-Z]'
```

I try to use :

```
'*[A-Z]*'
'%[A-Z]%'
```

but that didn't change anything

Comment: Maybe you have a table that is yours and you named it `mytable` but MySQL is not yours and it is not the same thing (or even related to) PostgreSQL.

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag. I think Stack Overflow adds that tag by default to all SQL questions. >:-( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275170/stop-generic-database-questions-from-getting-mysql-as-a-suggested-tag

Comment: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-like) `LIKE` does not support regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postgres there is the tilde operator for matching strings to regexes

```
select * from some_table where some_column ~ '^[A-Z]$'
```

will select records where `some_column` consists of only uppercase letters. Also `~*` is for case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: that is only for first letter

Comment: Yes, only the first. If you need arbitrary number of letters then use [A-Z]+ and if you want to match a string that has uppercase letters in it but might contain other characters as well then remove ^ and $ from the regex

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `~` operator to evaluate a regex:

```
SELECT id, field1 FROM mytable WHERE mytable ~ '[A-Z]'
```